# 3 Table Inner Join Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, conditional-statements

How would I go about writing a query in MySQL on 3 different tables? Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT distinct cool_id, example, table1.name
FROM tardis
INNER JOIN table1 
ON table1.unique_id = table2.unique_id
AND table1.unique_id='12345'
AND table2.status='active'
```

Now let's say that there is a column called 'planets' that exists in a 3rd table. How would I add that to this query to select 'planets' in addition to matching the other conditions in my current query? Also, please advise if an INNER JOIN is not the best choice for this.

Comment: What is `table2` in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col2
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.somecol = table3.othercol
```

The `ON` condition in the second join can refer to columns from `table1`, `table2`, or both.